# Swift - label updates with SwiftRangeSlider

Tags: ios, swift, rangeslider

I am trying to work with SwiftRangeSlider implemented by BrianCorbin:
https://github.com/BrianCorbin/SwiftRangeSlider

```
@IBOutlet weak var labelForRangeSlider: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var rangeSlider: RangeSlider!

@IBOutlet weak var submitButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    rangeSlider.updateLayerFrames()
}
...
```

And this shows:

[image: picture for labelForRangeSlider]

I want to update "Time", which is labelForRangeSlider, as rangeSlider's lowerValue and upperValue change.

Comment: You should include what you have tried with your codes and screenshots so that other users can easily understand your problem and help.

Comment: Sorry about that; I modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to add action for the event `.valueChanged` for `SwiftRangeSlider`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

   super.viewDidLoad()

   let rangeSlider: RangeSlider = RangeSlider(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 60))
   rangeSlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.rangeSliderValueChanged(slider:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
   self.view.addSubview(rangeSlider)
}


@IBAction func rangeSliderValueChanged(slider: RangeSlider) {
    print(slider.lowerValue)
}
```

Comment: Oh god, I totally missed that the RangeSlider class inherit UIControl...
Thank you for the answer. I didn't know that there was .valueChanged. Very apreciated

Answer (score 1):

Connect the `IBAction` below to the range slider in your storyboard and than you can change your label when you move the slider. You need to check `lowerValue` and `upperValue` of your slider.

```
@IBAction func rangeSliderValuesChanged(_ rangeSlider: slider) {
    labelForRangeSlider.text "Min: \(slider.lowerValue), Max: (slider.upperValue)")
}
```